# org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://192.168.1.45:8080 refused

Tags: android, android-emulator

I was trying to load a web page on the emulator. I was trying the following code.

```
package com.test.scraptest;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


      private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
          String response = "";
          for (String url : urls) {
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
              HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
              InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

              BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
              String s = "";
              while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                response += s;
              }

            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
              Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
            }
          }
          return response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
          textView.setText(result);
        }
      }

      public void onClick(View view) {
        DownloadWebPageTask task = new DownloadWebPageTask();
     //   new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        Toast ts=Toast.makeText(this, "this is a message",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) ;
        ts.show();
        task.execute(new String[] { "http://www.google.com" });

      }
}
```

Problem is, when I run the application I get the following error.

[image]

Comment: That typically means that the ip address trying to connect to the server was denied, maybe you check if your server has a blacklist or whitelist or IP addresses?

Comment: Is that the **actual** code you tried - and www.google.com resolved to  192.168.1.45?  Can you access google from the default web browser on the device?  You may not have the emulator-host networking setup right.

Comment: yes, I can access it from default browser and sametime from emulator browser also.

Comment: @chris, yes this is the actuall code, I am connected to network through proxy that's y I have given above IP

Comment: What do you mean by the emulator browser as distinct from the default browser?

Comment: Default browser is my IE browser on the machine.